# Duplicate folders created when I move or rename dropbox folders

Tags: dropbox

When I try to rename or move a folder in Dropbox (the desktop program), I end up having duplicates of the same, unedited folder. I am able to make changes online, but a number of my folders are too large to follow suit.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried contacting Dropbox about it? https://www.dropbox.com/help or https://www.dropbox.com/support

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether this will answer you.
While you create a folder in your system, it will be **sync** with the web account, which may take **few seconds** of time. If you rename or move the folder, whose sync is in process, the sync will be completed with new folder in web and then the second request to rename will be in process, but at the same time, as you have renamed or moved the new folder, the **web will sync** the desktop version which results in **duplication**.
When this happens to me often, my practice is to **wait for the sync to complete** before starting the second task related to the **same folder**.